# How to get value from a text field?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am creating a program where I can add and delete items. When added, I want the `TOTAL` panel to get values from `itemprice_textfield` when the button `ADD` is clicked.

```
private JFrame frame;
private JTextField itemname_textfield;
private JTextField itemprice_textfield;
private JButton add_button;
private JComboBox comboBox;
private JButton del_button;
private JLabel itemprice_label;
private JLabel itemname_label;
private JLabel lblNewLabel_3;
private JLabel totalamount_label;
private JTextField textField_2;
private double amount;
private JLabel bigger_itemname_label;
private JLabel bigger_itemprice_label;
private ArrayList <String> itemnames = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList <Double> itemprices = new ArrayList();
private JTable table;


//DefaultTableModel dtm;
//String header [] = new String [] {itemname_textfield, itemprice_textfield};



public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                EntapaCCE103LabExam1_Frame1 window = new EntapaCCE103LabExam1_Frame1();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public class lists{ // user defined method lists class
    public String itemname;
    public double price;
    
    public lists(String itemname, double price) 
    {
        this.itemname = itemname;
        this.price = price;
        
    }

    public lists(JTextField textField) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public lists(JTextField textField, JTextField textField_1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
                } // end

public EntapaCCE103LabExam1_Frame1() {
    initialize();
}



private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    
    JLabel big_title = new JLabel("MY ORDERS");
    big_title.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    big_title.setBounds(245, 11, 116, 52);
    frame.getContentPane().add(big_title);
    
    itemname_textfield = new JTextField(10); // name text
    itemname_textfield.setBounds(412, 268, 109, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(itemname_textfield);
    itemname_textfield.setColumns(10);
    
    itemprice_textfield = new JTextField(); // price text
    itemprice_textfield.setBounds(412, 330, 109, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(itemprice_textfield);
    itemprice_textfield.setColumns(10);
    
    add_button = new JButton("ADD ITEM");
    add_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
            String getname = itemname_textfield.getText(); // used to get the input string from user to transfer to the combo box
            comboBox.addItem(getname); // used to display the received string inputs
        }
    });
    add_button.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    add_button.setBounds(412, 361, 109, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(add_button);
    
    comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setBounds(412, 479, 109, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
    
    del_button = new JButton("DELETE ITEM");
    del_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            comboBox.removeItem(comboBox.getSelectedItem()); // used to delete the selected index in combo box.
        }
    });

    del_button.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    del_button.setBounds(412, 512, 109, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(del_button);
    
    itemprice_label = new JLabel("Enter Item Price:"); // label for item price
    itemprice_label.setBounds(412, 311, 109, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(itemprice_label); // used to display the text from label
    
    itemname_label = new JLabel("Enter Item Name:"); // label for item name
    itemname_label.setBounds(412, 249, 102, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(itemname_label); // used to display the text from label
    
    lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("OPERATION");
    lblNewLabel_3.setFont(new Font("Sitka Subheading", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(419, 185, 102, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_3);
    String getname = itemname_textfield.getText();
    
    totalamount_label = new JLabel("TOTAL: " + amount);              // amount here
    totalamount_label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    totalamount_label.setBounds(412, 130, 136, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(totalamount_label);

    bigger_itemname_label = new JLabel("ITEM NAME");
    bigger_itemname_label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    bigger_itemname_label.setBounds(84, 190, 96, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(bigger_itemname_label);
    
    bigger_itemprice_label = new JLabel("PRICE");
    bigger_itemprice_label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    bigger_itemprice_label.setBounds(245, 192, 46, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(bigger_itemprice_label);
    
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(39, 225, 322, 285);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    
    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    table.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
}
}
```

But I don't know how or what to do since I am new to Java GUI.

Also, please tell me if there's something weird in my code so that I can make improvement.

Comment: So, from a cursory examination of your code, I see the line `String getname = itemname_textfield.getText();` Do you suppose you could apply that same logic to `itemprice_textfield`? Also, just so you understand, we don't spruce up your code for you. You're supposed to ask questions about specific problems with your code and we're supposed to provide answers about your question. We're not in the business of scrubbing your code to find more problems -- that's *your* job.

Comment: In addition to the great advice above, here is a good demonstration of one of the first 15 or so reasons we should. [Use. Layouts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxV91.png)

Comment: Don't make every Swing component a class field.  You create a class field if and only if you use the field in more than one method.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  The [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern is very useful when creating Swing applications.